# If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $L$ a subgroup of $H$, is $K\oplus L$ a subgroup of $G\oplus H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is supposedly an easy and short proof, but I'm nevertheless stumped. The question was asked in two parts, the first of which was to show that every subgroup of $G\oplus H$ may not necessarily have the form $K\oplus L$, where $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $L$ a subgroup of $H$.

My proof:

Consider $H=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ where $H\leq \Bbb{Z}_2\oplus \Bbb{Z}_2$. Say $H=K\oplus L$. Then, $0,1\in K$ and $0,1\in L$, but $\Bbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$, so $K=L=\Bbb{Z}_2$. This implies that $H=\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus \Bbb{Z}_2$, which is obviously not true. That is, we have at least $(0,1)\not\in H$. Hence $H$ does not have the form $K\oplus L$.

The second part is to prove the converse is true: If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $L$ a subgroup of $H$, then $K\oplus L$ a subgroup of $G\oplus H$.

My attempt:

For $(k,l)\in K\oplus L$, $k\in K$ and $l\in L$. Because $K\leq G$ and $L\leq H$, we have $k\in G$ and $l\in H$.

I don't think I can straight up say, "Then $(k,l)\in G\oplus H$".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can straight up say it! If $k\in G$, $l\in H$, then $(k,h)\in G\oplus H$ by definition of $G\oplus H$.

Comment: Of course, that doesn't mean you're finished. You still need to show that $K\oplus L$ is closed under the group operation of $G\oplus H$, that if $g\in K\oplus L$, then $g^{-1}\in K\oplus L$, and that $K\oplus L$ is nonempty.

Comment: @Stahl Wait, really? Wow--I thought I needed something more than that. Thank you very much! The rest of the proof I think I can tackle confidently. :)